# Работа с файлами. Чтение/запись. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

В созданных файлах, согласно формату задания, юпитер делать все как надо. Но грабер  задания с сайта не принимает ответ(код). Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я допускаю ошибку?

К сожалению файлы прикрепить не могу. Но в первофм файле file.txt

```
FileText.txt
answer.txt
4
4shlack
5shlack
6shlack
```

3й  FileText.txt отсюда мы берем текст

```
 random text from internet. Anaconda is a free and open source
 distribution of the Python and R programming languages for data 
science and machine learning related applications, that aims to
 simplify package management and deployment. Package versions 
are managed by the package management system conda
```

В 2й файл answer.txt дописываем 4ю строку из FileText.txt

**Задание с сайта. Работа с файлами.**

- Прочитайте содержимое файла file.txt, содержащий 3 строки:
- имя файла с текстом. имя файла, куда необходимо дозаписать ответ
  (сохранив начало файла).
- номер строки (из файла с текстом), которую    надо привести к нижнему
  регистру и дозаписать в файл ответа.

Строки, как и элементы массива, нумеруются с 0.

Собственно мое решение:

```
# работа с первым файлом. Читаем строки
file = open('file.txt','r')

file_name_1 = file.readline()
file_name_1 = file_name_1[:-1]
#print(file_name_1)
file_name_3 = file.readline() # answer file string
file_name_3 = file_name_3[:-1]
#print(file_name_3)
number_line = int(file.readline()) # number line for second file to read lower_line
#print(number_line)
file.close()

# работа со вторым файлом. Чтение строки, по номеру полученному из первого файла, содержащегося в переменной number_line
#print(file_name_1)
file_2 = open(file_name_1,'r')
lower_line=[]
num = 1

for line in file_2:
    #print(num)
    #print(line)
    if num == ((number_line)-1):
        lower_line = file_2.readline()
        lower_line = lower_line.lower()
        break
    num+=1
#print(lower_line)
file_2.close()

# работа с 3м файлом. Открываем и записываем в него униженную строку из второго файла
file_3 = open(file_name_3,'a')
file_3.write(lower_line) 
file_3.close()
```

Comment: Задания с сайта https://stepik.org/lesson/113187/step/8?unit=87653 Грабер- система проверки. Jupyther notebook - браузерная idle для python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def read_first_n_lines(filename, n=1, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, **kwargs) as f:
        return [next(f).strip() for x in range(n)]

def read_nth_line(filename, n=0, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, **kwargs) as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            if i == n:
                return line
    return None


f1, f2, n = read_first_n_lines(r'file.txt', 3)
n = int(n)

with open(f2, 'a') as fout:
    fout.write(read_nth_line(f1, n).lower())
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш  код прошел проверку. 
Не могли бы подсказать в чем у меня была ошибка?

Comment: @AlexSapsay, сравните в Jupyter значение `lower_line` и `line = read_nth_line(f1, n).lower()`. Обратите внимание на начало и конец строки `lower_line`